# Sitecore Rocks - Package - Add Dependencies for Multiple Items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

VS Ultimate - 2013
sitecore rocks - 1.5.0.0

With sitecore rocks you can make a package and include the dependencies for any selected item. I would like to grab all of the dependencies for multiple items. Is there a way to do this?

...gregory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add dependencies manually for each root item as multi-select actions for Sitecore Rocks packages aren't currently supported.

Comment: grrrrr. Thanks, that's what I suspected was the case. Do you know if they are going to add that functionality?

Comment: Hard to say. The main code isn't open sourced but there is a contrib project on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks.Contrib) where you could submit an issue or give the lead Rocks dev Jakob Christensen a poke.